# Problema con query PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema con `PHP` que no he podido solucionar, los registros con `insert` funcionan perfectamente, pero el `delete` no funciona en la pagina.
aquí dejo el código que tengo con `PHP` en `ELIMINARequipo.php`.

el `$_POST['equipo']` lo obtengo de un `select` que cargo desde la base de datos y si envía correctamente la `ID_EQUIPO` seleccionada.

---

```html
<?php

require("bd.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
 echo "error";
 exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname) or die("No se encuentra");
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

$eq = $_POST['equipo'];

$sql = "DELETE INSUMO, EQUIPO FROM INSUMO JOIN EQUIPO ON INSUMO.ID_EQUIPO= EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO WHERE EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = $eq";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(!$resultado){
 echo $sql.mysqli_error();
}else{
header('Location: listadoequipo.php');
}


?>
```

Comment: Prueba con esto. $sql="DELETE INSUMO, EQUIPOS FROM INSUMO INNER JOIN EQUIPO ON INSUMO.ID_EQUIPO = EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO WHERE EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = $eq";

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99353/discussion-on-question-by-daniiela-alejandra-problema-con-query-php).

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error de sintaxis en tu código,  el ) paréntesis al final de delete.
La sintaxis correcta debería ser.

```
$sql="DELETE INSUMO, EQUIPOS FROM INSUMO JOIN EQUIPO ON INSUMO.ID_EQUIPO= EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO WHERE EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = $eq";
```

Te recomiendo siempre que tengas una clase de problema como ese, después de generar el Query, imprimirlo en pantalla para poder revisar las sintaxis.

Comment: gracias, arreglé el problema del paréntesis pero aún así sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Intenta de la siguiente manera: EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = ".$eq.""

Comment: @DaniielaAlejandra estás probando el sql antes de probarlo en php?

Comment: Sí, en la base de datos si funciona

Comment: Entonces el problema no es el sql

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código controlado, que hará que el programa hable, ocurra lo que ocurra.

He quitado algunas cosas innecesarias, como seleccionar la BD, luego puntualizamos si quieres.

He organizado mejor el código, incluyendo los archivos o creando las variables u objetos solamente cuando se esté seguro de que se necesitarán.

En la redirección he puesto un parámetro, si en efecto redirige, fíjate en la URL qué valor tiene `filas`.

Nada más, ahí debería informar de lo que está pasando realmente, cualquier cosa me lo dices en comentario a esta respuesta.

```
<?php
    $eq = ( !empty($_POST['equipo']) ) ? $_POST['equipo'] : NULL;
    if ($eq) {
        require("bd.php");
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn) {
            mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
            $sql = "DELETE INSUMO, EQUIPO FROM INSUMO JOIN EQUIPO ON INSUMO.ID_EQUIPO= EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO WHERE EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = $eq";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if(!$resultado){
                echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn);
            }else{
                $mRows=mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
                header("Location: listadoequipo.php?filas=$mRows");
            }           
        } else {
            echo "No hay conexión";
        }
    } else { 
        echo "No hay datos posteados"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Es raro ver una decisión con un `falsy` dentro `if ( $eq )`. Por lo que tengo entendido PHP no los comprende, yo usaba `empty()` en ese control.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob no entendí tu comentario, ... *con un `false` dentro ...* ¿?  Antes del `if` yo evalúo el POST con un ternario, asignado `NULL` a `$eq` si no hay nada en el POST y luego hago `if ($eq) { ` ... Es mi modo de proceder en estos casos y nunca he tenido problema.

Comment: Hasta donde yo recuerdo `null` no es interpretado por el `if` como un booleano. Yo hubiera utilizado directo en la decisión if( !empty( $_POST['equipo'] ) ) o `is_null()` sin pasar por la ternaria. Yo he tenido fallos de lógica evaluando como tú los `null`. Algo habré hecho mal

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob es interesante lo que me dices y en efecto, puede haber algún problema si por ejemplo el valor del post fuese `0`. Me gustaría tratar este asunto (quizá en alguna pregunta dedicada a él). En cualquier caso, a mi me interesa guardar en una variable el valor de `$eq` por el hecho de que eventualmente podría usarse en la consulta, por eso la asignación en el ternario.

Comment: Ok, con este código a veces pasa y carga el listado (pero no borra el dato), cuando si muestra el error dice que es un problema con la foreign key de la tabla padre, pero ese error no me sale en la BD y si lo ejecuta desde ahí, antes me arrojaba ese problema pero puse `set foreign_keys_check =0` y luego ya funcionó, será que debería hacer algo así en el codigo?

Comment: Ahhh, con razón, lo que pasa es que el registro que quieres eliminar @DaniielaAlejandra está amarrado a otra tabla, por eso es imposible hacerlo, por qué no lo pensé xd, pero sí, es esa cuestión si tienes un equipo `01, Cali`, digamos, en una tabla llamada `partido` por decirlo así, llamas a `01`, entonces va a generarte erro cuando quieres eliminar a `Cali`, yo lo que hago cuando quiero borrar datos, es no hacerlo, sino simplemente que el sistema no lo muestre y lo de por eliminado, con un campo `estado` que cambia de activo a inactivo cuando está o no eliminado

Comment: Espero que sea entendible

Comment: Daniela ya sospechaba eso. Estás intentando borrar un registro que tiene relación con otro(s) registro(s) de otra(s) tabla(s). El borrado del mismo resultaría en una inconsistencia de los datos y por tanto no te permite borrarlo. Eso es lo que se conoce como *Integridad referencial*. No te recomiendo que apagues el chequeo de llaves foráneas, porque podrías terminar teniendo un desastre en la BD. Es mejor que analices tu modelo de datos y adaptes el código. Por ejemplo, si hay restricciones de integridad debes revisarlas antes de borrar cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer tu sintaxis de tu query esta incorrecta pruebalo de esta forma:

```
"DELETE INSUMO, EQUIPOS FROM INSUMO JOIN EQUIPO ON INSUMO.ID_EQUIPO= EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO 
WHERE EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = '".$eq."'";
```

allí tu variable que es enviada a la BD sera entendida correctamente, ya que , el sql como sabras el texto debe de llegarle entre comillas simples(') y tu solo le mandabas:

```
"EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = ".$eq."";
```

el cual el se entiende como  EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = windows10.

Debiendo de ser asi:

```
"EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = '".$eq."'";
```

el cual lo entenderá así EQUIPO.ID_EQUIPO = 'windows10'